# how to increase heap size in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

**I'm calling a neo4j movie lens project from Github**

and once my API is ready when I'm testing the features it says that your increase your heap size in order to make this query run as it requires a lot of memory and time so from where do I have to change the heap size of neo4j in particularly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the page which describes it. https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/

You need to edit the neo4j.conf and set the heap size with these settings,

dbms.memory.heap.initial_size

and

dbms.memory.heap.max_size

Set it to a value you think is appropriate to start.

Go through the first link carefully and set other settings as well.

Also turn on the query logging to see how your queries are performing.

Try the settings and change them if needed.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but I dont have any conf file as im calling it through docker i only have docker files that i run so how to configure conf file please let me know the solution im stuck on this one problem since 4 days :/

Comment: 1. You can login to docker container and change the conf file setting 

    https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-ssh-into-docker-container 

    https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

2. Setup neo4j another way. Read the installation instruction and see if neo4j 
under osx, windows or neo4j desktop is right for you.

    https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/

3. Install it in a linux vm.

Spin off a linux vm using virtualbox , install neo4j and configure it.